# vagrant will never be able to ssh to my ubuntu box even while creating.

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I have an issue with Vagrant box bento/ubuntu-16.04 and only this box vagrant will never be able to ssh to the built VM even while creating

I tried to configure ssh once by using key and once by username and password and still getting same error, tried to delete the box and add it again, same issue

using:- 
ubuntu 16.04 as main OS
Vagrant 1.9.4
Virtualbox: 5.0.40
vagrantbox: bento/ubuntu-16.04
Vagrant file "ssh using password"

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
  config.vm.hostname = "myubuntu"
  config.ssh.username = "soso"
  config.ssh.password = "soso"

end
```

here is what happens when I run vagrant using the above vagrant file.

```
$vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: issue_default_1497215548452_86309
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2202.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2202 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2202
    default: SSH username: soso
    default: SSH auth method: password
soso@127.0.0.1's password:
soso@127.0.0.1's password:
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
soso@127.0.0.1's password:
soso@127.0.0.1's password:
soso@127.0.0.1's password:
soso@127.0.0.1's password:
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
soso@127.0.0.1's password:
```

and here is part of "--debug" log when it start to ask me for password. this keeps loops and show off every second. I am not sure if it is related.

```
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "11fd95c4-1632-4fe9-93d8-4e3641e76b72", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: name="issue_default_1497215719513_409"
groups="/"
ostype="Ubuntu (64-bit)"
UUID="11fd95c4-1632-4fe9-93d8-4e3641e76b72"
CfgFile="/home/abbas/VirtualBox VMs/issue_default_1497215719513_409/issue_default_1497215719513_409.vbox"
SnapFldr="/home/abbas/VirtualBox VMs/issue_default_1497215719513_409/Snapshots"
LogFldr="/home/abbas/VirtualBox VMs/issue_default_1497215719513_409/Logs"
hardwareuuid="11fd95c4-1632-4fe9-93d8-4e3641e76b72"
memory=1024
pagefusion="off"
vram=8
cpuexecutioncap=100
hpet="off"
chipset="piix3"
firmware="BIOS"
cpus=1
pae="on"
longmode="on"
cpuid-portability-level=0
bootmenu="messageandmenu"
boot1="disk"
boot2="dvd"
boot3="none"
boot4="none"
acpi="on"
ioapic="on"
biossystemtimeoffset=0
rtcuseutc="on"
hwvirtex="on"
nestedpaging="on"
largepages="on"
vtxvpid="on"
vtxux="on"
paravirtprovider="default"
VMState="running"
VMStateChangeTime="2017-06-11T21:15:21.448000000"
monitorcount=1
accelerate3d="off"
accelerate2dvideo="off"
teleporterenabled="off"
teleporterport=0
teleporteraddress=""
teleporterpassword=""
tracing-enabled="off"
tracing-allow-vm-access="off"
tracing-config=""
autostart-enabled="off"
autostart-delay=0
defaultfrontend=""
storagecontrollername0="IDE Controller"
storagecontrollertype0="PIIX4"
storagecontrollerinstance0="0"
storagecontrollermaxportcount0="2"
storagecontrollerportcount0="2"
storagecontrollerbootable0="on"
storagecontrollername1="SATA Controller"
storagecontrollertype1="IntelAhci"
storagecontrollerinstance1="0"
storagecontrollermaxportcount1="30"
storagecontrollerportcount1="1"
storagecontrollerbootable1="on"
"IDE Controller-0-0"="none"
"IDE Controller-0-1"="none"
"IDE Controller-1-0"="none"
"IDE Controller-1-1"="none"
"SATA Controller-0-0"="/home/abbas/VirtualBox VMs/issue_default_1497215719513_409/ubuntu-16.04-amd64-disk001.vmdk"
"SATA Controller-ImageUUID-0-0"="ada6bc87-b77f-4697-852d-313419f46319"
natnet1="nat"
macaddress1="080027E889C6"
cableconnected1="on"
nic1="nat"
nictype1="82540EM"
nicspeed1="0"
mtu="0"
sockSnd="64"
sockRcv="64"
tcpWndSnd="64"
tcpWndRcv="64"
Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2202,,22"
nic2="none"
nic3="none"
nic4="none"
nic5="none"
nic6="none"
nic7="none"
nic8="none"
hidpointing="ps2mouse"
hidkeyboard="ps2kbd"
uart1="off"
uart2="off"
uart3="off"
uart4="off"
lpt1="off"
lpt2="off"
audio="pulse"
clipboard="disabled"
draganddrop="disabled"
SessionName="headless"
VideoMode="800,600,32"@0,0 1
vrde="on"
vrdeport=5925
vrdeports="5925"
vrdeaddress="127.0.0.1"
vrdeauthtype="null"
vrdemulticon="off"
vrdereusecon="off"
vrdevideochannel="off"
vrdeproperty[TCP/Ports]="5925"
vrdeproperty[TCP/Address]="127.0.0.1"
usb="off"
ehci="off"
xhci="off"
SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="vagrant"
SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="/home/abbas/issue"
VRDEActiveConnection="off"
VRDEClients=0
vcpenabled="off"
vcpscreens=0
vcpfile="/home/abbas/VirtualBox VMs/issue_default_1497215719513_409/issue_default_1497215719513_409.webm"
vcpwidth=1024
vcpheight=768
vcprate=512
vcpfps=25
GuestMemoryBalloon=0
GuestOSType="Linux26_64"
GuestAdditionsRunLevel=2
GuestAdditionsVersion="5.1.21 r115005"
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox Base Driver=50,1497215732634
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox System Service=50,1497215735252
GuestAdditionsFacility_Seamless Mode=0,1497215732634
GuestAdditionsFacility_Graphics Mode=0,1497215732634
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
```

Vagrant file " using vagrant isecure key"

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
  config.vm.hostname = "myubuntu"
  config.ssh.username = "soso"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  ## making sure it is using the right key
  config.ssh.private_key_path = '/home/abbas/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key'
end
```

here is what happens when I run vagrant using the above vagrant file.

```
$vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: issue_default_1497216190372_85398
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2202.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2202 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2202
    default: SSH username: soso
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use your own `username` to login unless you have created its own account. The default convention for public box is to create a `vagrant` user, so unless its clearly specified or it you have created your own box (through packer for example) with a specific user, you'll need to login with `vagrant` user.

remove your `config.ssh.username` and `config.ssh.password` or replace with `vagrant` user and it will let you login